# What is the difference between self and cls argument in classmethod decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class First:
    @classmethod
    def hello(self):
        print(123)

class Second:  
    @classmethod
    def hello(cls):
        print(123)

obj1 = First()
obj2 = Second()

print(obj1.hello())
print(obj1.hello())
```

I am not getting any error while calling `obj1` (with `self` as argument) and `obj2` (with `cls` as argument). Why not? Is the classmethod decorator  able to use `cls`/`self`?

Comment: It's just a *name*. We call the instance in an instance method `self` **by convention**, and the class in a class method `cls` the same, but you could switch the names, or use `foo`, or anything else. As long as you're consistent between definition and usage, it will work like any other parameter.

Answer (score 0):

One will be understood by every reasonably experienced Python programmer.
The other one will confuse every reasonably experienced Python programmer.

The *first argument* of a classmethod is a class and should be called `cls`. You can give it any other name in your code, but that's a bad idea, because it still is a class.